# Site uses SSL, but what about JSON queries?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl

I am a novice to SSL, but I got a certificate, set my hosting up, and I get the green padlock on my site, which is now using SSL.

In my MVC app, I decorated all my controller methods, globally, using:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

    var useSsl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Protocol"].ToLower();
    if (useSsl == "https")
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

The config setting to come out of SSL when debugging.

However, are my json queries also SSL protected?

Example call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Category/GetSubCategories',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ categoryId: id }),
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
```

...

Will these be secure, or do I need to ensure they use SSL as well?

The controller methods they call should be covered by the global RequiresSSL, but I'm not sure.

For example:

```
public JsonResult AddNewLine(TransactionModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

I have that in a controller, that is called from a page that is on https://...

Will the request and reply be encrypted?

The initial connection is HTTP, and thereafter, HTTPS. I am thinking that is due to all my controller methods being 'RequiresSSL'?

[image]

Some mention below about me confusing things, but I'm unclear what I am confusing. Also, the (At time of editing this) -2 negatives on my post, makes me thing I have asked or done something wrong, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about this completely wrong. It's like asking "my car's engine broke, I wonder if my oven will work when I cook dinner tonight?" They're really unrelated.

If you want the client to access the site va HTTPS, then have a URL rewrite that converts the URL to HTTP from HTTPS. There is no need to make a ton of settings to your controllers.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't be worrying about connection protocol in your controllers. Remember separation of concerns. I don't know exactly what a "JSON Query" is. If you're talking about AJAX calls you're making to you site, they'll use whatever protocol is specified in the route to the API end point. If no protocol is specified there, it uses the protocol of the site. Generally most browsers will show a dialog if you try to access an HTTP resource from a site that was loaded via HTTPS anyways.

Comment: Assuming URL rewrite will solve all the SSL/TLS access problems is completely wrong. The redirection only happens *after* the initial plain HTTP request has been made, which may leak information and can also be vulnerable to downgrade attacks (see [longer explanation here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)). What matters is that all the links presented to the client use `https://` when they should, possibly automatically for relative links (although there's always an issue with the starting point, which HSTS can help with).

Comment: @Bruno If a client chooses to visit your site with HTTP, then there's nothing you can do to prevent them sending an HTTP request with information. You can however coerce the client to rerequest with HTTPS (using a redirect), and then all subsequent communication will be HTTPS. Regardless, that all seems like information overload when the OP simply wanted to get HTTPS up and running. Nowhere did I state or imply that URL rewriting is a magic solution that fixes everything.

Comment: All subsequent communication will only be HTTPS **if** the links used by the page use `https://` or are relative (or HSTS is used), which is unfortunately not always the case, especially when people assume a systematic redirect will fix this. What really matters in this question is what the URLs presented on the page for those AJAX requests use.

Comment: @Bruno I already said this, in the first comment on this answer. Please don't clutter up the answer.

Comment: I'm no closer to know what I am doing wrong though. When I connect to my site, using http: .. the controller method, decorated with RequiresSSL ... seems to change the url to https automatically. So, what you're saying is that the initial request in http (Which might include sensitive data?) But all POST commands are 'RequiresSSL', so isn't everything secure then? I'm unsure what I should be doing to resolve this percieved issue. Can you alter your answer?

Comment: @Craig if you're on an HTTPS connection and all paths to the server side are relative, then the communication will be HTTPS. If you use absolute paths (full URL) then it depends on the protocol you specify in the URL. Feel free to verify using your browser's debugging tools or something like Wireshark or Fiddler to verify the traffic.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my question, as I am more confused than ever now. :) I am on HTTPS, as the address shows a green padlock, and the URL goes to HTTPS (Even if I type in my address without https).

Comment: You probably have some sort of redirect that sends you from HTTP to HTTPS. I'm just guessing, but if you want the traffic you'll see an initial HTTP request, followed by an HTTP 301 or 302 redirect from the server, followed by your browser re-requesting over an HTTPS connection. Therefore the initial request and response isn't secure, but all subsequent communication is. That's about all you can do, short of preventing all non HTTPS communication (which would be a bad experience for your users, though perhaps appropriate if what you're exposing is an API)

Comment: Thanks Mason. I added a screenshot. I believe you're spot on with regards the redirect. The initial request is unsecure (Not worried), but then it seems MVC (??) forces it to redo the request using HTTPS. So, it seems I'm OK then?

Comment: I'm not specifically familiar with the RequireSSL attribute, but something definitely redirected your browser to do HTTPS after the initial request. Since you'd probably know if you added some sort of rewrite rule, it's probably safe to assume that RequireSSL is what did it. So if you just wanted to make sure that all traffic after the initial request is encrypted, then you've accomplished that.

Comment: Note that it's probably easier to implement a [rewrite rule](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/) at the server level rather than decorate all controller methods with RequireSSL.